# Problema com autenticação de API no android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou com problema na autenticação de um clone de UBER executado no Android Studio. A API é executada na classe main:

```
  package com.uber.sdk.rides.samples.cmdline;

    import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
    import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
    import com.google.api.client.util.store.AbstractDataStoreFactory;
    import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
    import com.uber.sdk.core.auth.OAuth2Credentials;
    import com.uber.sdk.core.client.CredentialsSession;
    import com.uber.sdk.core.client.SessionConfiguration;
    import com.uber.sdk.rides.client.services.RidesService;
    import com.uber.sdk.rides.client.UberRidesApi;
    import com.uber.sdk.rides.client.error.ApiError;
    import com.uber.sdk.rides.client.error.ClientError;
    import com.uber.sdk.rides.client.error.ErrorParser;
    import com.uber.sdk.rides.client.model.UserProfile;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import retrofit2.Response;

    /**
     * Demonstrates how to authenticate the user and load their profile via the command line.
     */
    public final class GetUserProfile {

        private GetUserProfile() {}

        private static LocalServerReceiver localServerReceiver;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


            SessionConfiguration config = createSessionConfiguration();
            Credential credential = authenticate(System.getProperty("user.name"), config);
            //Create an authenticator for Credential to use in our Session
            CredentialsSession session = new CredentialsSession(config, credential);

            // Create the Uber API service object once the User is authenticated
            UberRidesApi uberRidesApi = UberRidesApi.with(session).build();

            RidesService service = uberRidesApi.createService();
            // Fetch the user's profile.
            System.out.println("Calling API to get the user's profile");
            Response<UserProfile> response = service.getUserProfile().execute();

            ApiError apiError = ErrorParser.parseError(response);
            if (apiError != null) {
                // Handle error.
                ClientError clientError = apiError.getClientErrors().get(0);
                System.out.printf("Unable to fetch profile. %s", clientError.getTitle());
                System.exit(0);
                return;
            }

            // Success!
            UserProfile userProfile = response.body();
            System.out.printf("Logged in as %s%n", userProfile.getEmail());
            System.exit(0);



        }

        /**
         * Authenticate the given user. If you are distributing an installed application, this method
         * should exist on your server so that the client ID and secret are not shared with the end
         * user.
         */
        private static Credential authenticate(String userId, SessionConfiguration config) throws Exception {
            OAuth2Credentials oAuth2Credentials = createOAuth2Credentials(config);

            // First try to load an existing Credential. If that credential is null, authenticate the user.
            Credential credential = oAuth2Credentials.loadCredential(userId);
            if (credential == null || credential.getAccessToken() == null) {
                // Send user to authorize your application.
                System.out.printf("Add the following redirect URI to your developer.uber.com application: %s%n",
                        oAuth2Credentials.getRedirectUri());
                System.out.println("Press Enter when done.");

                System.in.read();

                // Generate an authorization URL.
                String authorizationUrl = oAuth2Credentials.getAuthorizationUrl();
                System.out.printf("In your browser, navigate to: %s%n", authorizationUrl);
                System.out.println("Waiting for authentication...");

                // Wait for the authorization code.
                String authorizationCode = localServerReceiver.waitForCode();
                System.out.println("Authentication received.");

                // Authenticate the user with the authorization code.
                credential = oAuth2Credentials.authenticate(authorizationCode, userId);
            }
            localServerReceiver.stop();

            return credential;
        }

        /**
         * Creates an {@link OAuth2Credentials} object that can be used by any of the servlets.
         */
        private static OAuth2Credentials createOAuth2Credentials(SessionConfiguration sessionConfiguration) throws Exception {




            // Store the users OAuth2 credentials in their home directory.
            File credentialDirectory =
                    new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + ".uber_credentials");
            credentialDirectory.setReadable(true, true);
            credentialDirectory.setWritable(true, true);
            // If you'd like to store them in memory or in a DB, any DataStoreFactory can be used.
            AbstractDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(credentialDirectory);

            // Build an OAuth2Credentials object with your secrets.
            return new OAuth2Credentials.Builder()
                    .setCredentialDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                    .setRedirectUri(sessionConfiguration.getRedirectUri())
                    .setClientSecrets(sessionConfiguration.getClientId(), sessionConfiguration.getClientSecret())
                    .build();
        }

        public static SessionConfiguration createSessionConfiguration() throws Exception {
            // Load the client ID and secret from {@code resources/secrets.properties}. Ideally, your
            // secrets would not be kept local. Instead, have your server accept the redirect and return
            // you the accessToken for a userId.
            Properties secrets = loadSecretProperties();

            String clientId = secrets.getProperty("clientId");
            String clientSecret = secrets.getProperty("clientSecret");

            if (clientId.equals("INSERT_CLIENT_ID_HERE") || clientSecret.equals("INSERT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE")) {
                throw new IllegalAccessException("Please enter your client ID and secret in the resources/secrets.properties file.");
            }

            // Start a local server to listen for the OAuth2 redirect.
            localServerReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8181).build();
            String redirectUri = localServerReceiver.getRedirectUri();

            return new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                    .setClientId(clientId)
                    .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .setRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                    .build();

        }

        /**
         * Loads the application's secrets.
         */
        private static Properties loadSecretProperties() throws Exception {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            InputStream propertiesStream = GetUserProfile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("secrets.properties");
            if (propertiesStream == null) {
                // Fallback to file access in the case of running from certain IDEs.
                File buildPropertiesFile = new File("src/main/resources/secrets.properties");
                if (buildPropertiesFile.exists()) {
                    properties.load(new FileReader(buildPropertiesFile));
                } else {
                    buildPropertiesFile = new File("samples/cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/secrets.properties");
                    if (buildPropertiesFile.exists()) {
                        properties.load(new FileReader(buildPropertiesFile));
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find secrets.properties");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                properties.load(propertiesStream);
            }
            return properties;
        }
    }
```

E obtendo a seguinte exception:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Please enter your client ID and secret in the resources/secrets.properties file.
            at com.uber.sdk.rides.samples.cmdline.GetUserProfile.createSessionConfiguration(GetUserProfile.java:158)
            at com.uber.sdk.rides.samples.cmdline.GetUserProfile.main(GetUserProfile.java:58)
```

Comment: O erro indica que você deve ter seu `cliente ID` e seu `secret` informados no arquivo `resources/secrets.properties`. Esses dados estão lá?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu estava tentando autenticar somente pela API, porém preciso criar também uma autenticação do servidor!